# tikz-cd: alignment and label placement of snake-like arrows

Tags: tikz-cd

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    {C_{n+1}'} & {C_{n+1}} & {C_{n+1}''} \\
    {C_n'} & {C_n} & {C_n''} \\
    {C_{n-1}'} & {C_{n-1}} & {C_{n-1}''}
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=2-1, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=2-3]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=3-2]
    \arrow[from=3-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=Z1}]
    \arrow[from=1-3, to=2-1, "\delta"', rounded corners,
             to path={ -- ([xshift=2ex]\tikztostart.east)
                       |- (Z1) [near end]\tikztonodes
                       -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west)
                       -- (\tikztotarget)}]
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=3-2, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=Z2}]
    \arrow[from=2-3, to=3-1, "\delta"', rounded corners,
             to path={ -- ([xshift=2ex]\tikztostart.east)
                       |- (Z2) [near end]\tikztonodes
                       -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west)
                       -- (\tikztotarget)}]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. How to horizontally align the two snake-like arrows?
2. How to place the label `\delta` on the right side of the arrow?

Thank you in advance for your suggestion!

(Also, it was quite a surprise to me when I first learned this usage of `1-1`, `2-1` etc. from [quiver](https://q.uiver.app), because with this one can write all the elements as a table and then write the arrows afterwards, which greatly increase the code readability. However, it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the documentation of `tikz-cd`, or did I miss something?)

Comment: The node identification by row and column is described in the manual in section 2.3 (Absolute placement of arrows) at the bottom of page 8 in the section on `to` and `from`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the node contents have different widths, use the center of the nodes for alignment. You will need to increase the `xshift` to compensate. To place the `\delta`, use `\pos=.25` and remove the `'` from the description.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    {C_{n+1}'} & {C_{n+1}} & {C_{n+1}''} \\
    {C_n'} & {C_n} & {C_n''} \\
    {C_{n-1}'} & {C_{n-1}} & {C_{n-1}''}
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=2-1, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=2-3]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=3-2]
    \arrow[from=3-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=Z1}]
    \arrow[from=1-3, to=2-1, "\delta", rounded corners,
             to path={ -- ([xshift=6ex]\tikztostart.center)
                       |- (Z1) [pos=.25]\tikztonodes
                       -| ([xshift=-6ex]\tikztotarget.center)
                       -- (\tikztotarget)}]
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=3-2, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=Z2}]
    \arrow[from=2-3, to=3-1, "\delta", rounded corners,
             to path={ -- ([xshift=6ex]\tikztostart.center)
                       |- (Z2) [pos=.25]\tikztonodes
                       -| ([xshift=-6ex]\tikztotarget.center)
                       -- (\tikztotarget)}]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer both questions.

1. Every cell need the same width:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[
    every cell/.style={
        minimum width=.85cm
        % or: text width=.85cm
    }
]
    % your code
\end{tikzcd}
```

2. You have to replace `near end` for example by:

```
near start, right=.35cm
```